# Themes and other options not loading from MELPA

Tags: python, themes, package-repositories

While following a tutorial on editing python using Emacs (https://realpython.com/emacs-the-best-python-editor/) I've been unable to install better-defaults, line numbers and any themes or return to default settings.

[Emacs version 26.1]

I used the init.el file offered in the tutorial:

```
;; .emacs.d/init.el


;; ===================================

;; MELPA Package Support

;; ===================================

;; Enables basic packaging support

(require 'package)


;; Adds the Melpa archive to the list of available repositories

(add-to-list 'package-archives

             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)


;; Initializes the package infrastructure

(package-initialize)


;; If there are no archived package contents, refresh them

(when (not package-archive-contents)

  (package-refresh-contents))


;; Installs packages

;;

;; myPackages contains a list of package names

(defvar myPackages

  '(better-defaults                 ;; Set up some better Emacs defaults

    material-theme                  ;; Theme

    )

  )


;; Scans the list in myPackages

;; If the package listed is not already installed, install it

(mapc #'(lambda (package)

          (unless (package-installed-p package)

            (package-install package)))

      myPackages)


;; ===================================

;; Basic Customization

;; ===================================


(setq inhibit-startup-message t)    ;; Hide the startup message

(load-theme 'material t)            ;; Load material theme

(global-linum-mode t)               ;; Enable line numbers globally


;; User-Defined init.el ends here
```

The first time I ran this it correctly changed the theme but none of the other options work. I'm now unable to change the theme or restore defaults (deleting local files relating to Emacs doesn't seem to help and searches for more information on this problem becomes an instant rabbit hole.)

It seems to be unable to access the packages being requested from MELPA, although the code seems correct when compared to the Emacs wiki so next steps are unclear.

I've included a screenshot of the error message as trying to copy from Emacs is proving to be another can of worms.

[image: Error Message]

Just getting started with Emacs so it's possible I'm missing some unwritten rule, please be as explicit as possible in your answer.

Comment: What version of Emacs are you using? It is failing while trying to connect to an https server, and some older versions of Emacs have trouble connecting to modern TLS1.3 servers. Also, you really should use https for connecting to MELPA as well. No point in throwing away security.

Comment: I'm using 26.1 and will throw in the s for https

Comment: Ah. Can you try upgrading Emacs to version 26.3 or 27.2? If that doesn’t help, try setting `url-debug` to `t`, then call `package-refresh-contents`. You will get a buffer called `*URL-DEBUG*` which contains a bunch of log messages; perhaps there will be sufficient information there to diagnose the problem.

Comment: thanks, updated to 27.2 and everything works perfectly